# Exporting audio in Nuendo five

Tags: nuendo

I am using Nuendo 5 on a PC. I have several tracks in my project and I want to export them as one stereo MP3.

When I click *File ⇾ Export*, then *Audio Mixdown...,* the “Export Audio Mixdown” box opens, but it doesn't appear to have a box for me to check for a stereo mix down.

Can anyone help, because I am currently exporting in mono, and it's driving me nuts!

Answer (score 1):

This pic is from Cubase 7.5, but the export window hasn't changed much over the years... Do you not have the mono down mix option?

[image]

Comment: i found some one on line an hour ago who talked it through with me, thanks ever so much for your reply. in the old version it used to have a "stereo interleaved" box that one ticked, they have now changed it to l/r channels i had nothing ticked, am getting stereo now, thanks. your a star!

Comment: Glad you got it - it had been so long since I saw v5, I wasn't sure how the Export window looked back then. :-)

Comment: You know, Nuendo and Cubase doesn't follow the same version numbers, Nuendo only recently entered version 6.5 ;-)

Comment: Yes, they're 1 out & have been for years. One day they'll get them in sync, but it won't be this year. Expect to see Cubase 8 & Nuendo 7 pretty soon ;-)